# How to access a class constructor parameter from the another class parameter

Tags: c++, class, parameters, constructor, arguments

## STRUGGLING WITH C++ CONSTRUCTOR ARGUMENTS

So, I've just came from TS/JS/Py and trying to understand C++ concepts. But I'm struggling with using the parameter of constructor of the class FOR declaring default value for an argument. Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
double Phythagorean_Hypotenuse (int& a, int& b ) {
    return sqrt((a * a) + (b * b));
};

class Triangle {
    public:
      int a;
      int b;
      double c;
      Triangle(int a_param, int b_param, double c_param = Phythagorean_Hypotenuse(a_param, b_param)) {
            a = a_param;
            b = b_param;
            c = c_param;
      }
};
```

and inside of the main function

```
Triangle mytri_1(10, 20);
std::cout << mytri_1.a << std:endl;
```

But when I try to run this code, IDE is throwing me some errors like

```
[Error] 'a_param' was not declared in this scope
```

or

```
[Error] call to 'Triangle::Triangle(int, int, double)' uses the default argument for parameter 3, which is not yet defined
```

So, please, can someone who can fix this answer the question?

Thanks.

Comment: and also sorry guys, for poorish messy code, I'm pretty noob at this, but still learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues that prevent your code from compiling, namely:

1. Constructors do not have return type.
2. `double c_param = Phythagorean_Hypotenuse(a_param, b_param)` is not valid for a parameter, `a_param, b_param` will not be recognized.

Recommend change:

Since the result of a hypothenuse calculation will most likely be a decimal value, `c` should be a `double`.

You can do something like this:

[**Running sample**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QzMdnHyA6NW4zlwD)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double Phythagorean_Hypotenuse (int& a, int& b ) {
    return sqrt((a * a) + (b * b));
};

class Triangle {
    public:
      int a;
      int b;
      double c; //should be double

      //initializer list is a good practice for member initialization
      Triangle(int a_param, int b_param) 
          : a(a_param), b(b_param), c(Phythagorean_Hypotenuse(a, b)) {} 
};

int main(){

    Triangle mytri_1(10, 20);
    std::cout << mytri_1.a << std::endl;
    std::cout << mytri_1.b << std::endl;
    std::cout << mytri_1.c << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
10
20
22.3607
```

Comment: Thanks, I _really_ appreciate your help, @anastaciu.

Comment: @azizbekmasharibov, thank you my friend, I'm glad my answer helped you.

Answer (score 2):

As the compiler is pointing out, the other constructor arguments are not available as default parameters for the c_param argument. Rather than using default values, just overload the constructor, including one that just accepts 2 parameters. This constructor can then invoke the other constructor that accepts all 3:

```
 // Constructor overload that accepts all 3 parameters
 Triangle(int a_param, int b_param, double c_param):
  a(a_param), b(b_param), c(c_param) {
  }

  // Constructor overload that accepts just a and b, call the other constructor
  // to set all 3 members
  Triangle(int a_param, int b_param):
  Triangle(a_param, b_param, Phythagorean_Hypotenuse(a_param, b_param)) {
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Default parameter values cannot reference other parameters.  You can define two overloads, one of which delegates to the other, to do what you want:

```
class Triangle {
public:
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;

    Triangle(double a_param, double b_param, double c_param)
        : a{a_param},
          b{b_param},
          c{c_param}
    {}

    Triangle(double a_param, double b_param)
        : Triangle{a_param, b_param, Phythagorean_Hypotenuse(a_param, b_param)}
    {}
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a878d59799785eb)

---

A few other notes:

- Class constructors do not have a return type.  I changed `void Triangle(...)` to `Triangle(...)`
- I used constructor initialization lists instead of assignment in the constructor's body.  There's likely no difference for small primitive values like `int`s or `double`s, but it's a good habit to get into and can make a big difference for more complex types
- `int` doesn't make sense for the type of `c` (or `a` or `b` for that matter).  The sides of a triangle are unlikely to all be integers
- There's no reason to pass parameters to `Pythagorean_Hypotenuse` by reference.  It's simpler and likely faster to pass them by value

Comment: Wow, thanks for that clear explanation, really appreciate it. In short, thanks so much, @Miles Budnek!